# Java Peer Not Authenticated

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I'm trying to get OAuth through SoundCloud set up, but I'm having tremendous trouble. My newest issue is this:

I have the user login through a popup window which is connected to SoundCloud. It gives me a back a code once the user logs in. This is all working; however, the next step is failing for me. Once I have the code, I run this snippet of Java code:

```
URI redir = new URI("http://localhost:9000/auth/soundcloudcapturetoken");
ApiWrapper api = new ApiWrapper(SC_CLIENT_ID, SC_CLIENT_SECRET, redir, null, Env.SANDBOX);
Token authToken = api.authorizationCode(code);
```

Java fails on the api.authorizationCode(code) line with this error:

```
SSLPeerUnverifiedException occured : peer not authenticated
```

I snooped around online, and stumbled upon this post: http://davidjb.com/blog/2012/02/java-http-request-fails-with-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated

It suggested that I add the two mentioned certs to my java cacerts file(s). I added the two certificates to both my jdk and jre, but my app still fails with the same error. Is there something I am missing here?

As a side note, I am currently using this api to access SoundCloud: https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SoundCloud dev here.

Are you trying to use the sandbox (i.e. connecting to https://api.sandbox-soundcloud.com) ? If so, I was trying to reproduce your issue and just realised that our certificate for that host expired, we are deploying a new certificate as we speak, really sorry about that.

Also, you can find help from SoundCloud engineers in our mailing list: http://bit.ly/yqcubH

Comment: I'm not sure which api I'm using, I guess which ever comes by default with the SoundCloud Java SDK. I'll try it out again soon and see if it works! Thanks!

Comment: Expired certificate was the cause of our "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated"